# Cannot get Unity to work - help!

Tags: 12.04, unity, lubuntu

I bought an older, refurbished Dell Latitude D600 - Pentium M / 1 GB RAM / 100 GB HDD with no OS -  it is a non-pae so I installed Lubuntu 10.04.  I did the Update Manager and now it shows I have the following:

- Distribution:  Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS
- Kernel:  Linux 3.2.0-49-generic (i686)
- Desktop Environment:  LXDE (Lubuntu)

I really want to use Unity, but I cannot figure out how to get it working.  My desktop still shows the same type of Lubuntu interface before my update.  I know Unity is installed as I saw it in the Synaptic Package Manager under installed packages.

How do I get Unity to operate so I have the cool desktop interface?

Please help anyone as I have tried everything (with my limited computer knowledge!)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the ubuntu-desktop package is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now logout.

At the login page there is an option to change the environment from LXDE to Unity.

Login and you should be in Unity.

---

It would be wise to stick with LXDE. A machine with 1GB of RAM and a Pentium series processor will have a hard time running Unity, if it will work at all.

Answer (score 0):

go to Ubuntu software centre and search ubuntu-desktop and install 400 MB. restart  and then login Ubuntu desktop.